# Как установить кодировку при отправке Ajax запроса?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть форма комментария

```
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNew", "Comment", new AjaxOptions {
                    HttpMethod = "POST"
                }))
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="custom-comment-identify">Идентификатор</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="custom-comment-identify" name="custom-comment-identify" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="custom-comment-field">Комментарий</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="custom-comment-field" name="custom-comment-field" autofocus></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Добавить</button>
                }
```

и таблица `comments`

```
CREATE TABLE asteriskcdrdb.comments (
  Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  LinkedId varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  Comment varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
CHECKSUM = 0,
COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
ROW_FORMAT = fixed;
```

Добавляю комментарий, но в базе он отображается как `????? ???`. Подскажите пожалуйста, может я забыл где то проставить кодировку?

Comment: Какая кодировка на самой странице, где расположен ваш код ajax-запроса? Тоже utf8 или cp1251?

Comment: Кодировка страницы utf8..

Comment: Хорошо. А если брейкпойнт поставить на AddNew в контроллере и посмотреть данные - что приходит с клиента, в какой кодировке?

Comment: Приходят русскими буквами без всяких ???.

Comment: Тогда вам следует разбираться на участке сохранения в базу данных. Вы и код не предоставили этой части, да и я с mysql из-под c# не работал, так что тут мало что подскажу. Но раз до кода приходит верно - проблема на последующих участках.